# How to Query Firebase with Swift for specific values

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to the Swift and Firebase world. Recently I got stuck trying to sum specific field values in my Firebase database.

Here is a screen-grab of my db structure.

[image]
I would like to sum the "Number" values, but only if the `"Sender" = aa@bb.com (only the "aa@bb.com" sum of "Number" values)`

I managed to sum all "number" values in the db, but filtering to a certain email values is too much of a challenge for me so far.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Everything you need to know is in [the firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)

Comment: Query for where `sender isEqualTo aa@bb.com` and sum locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this take **local variable Num** of integer type and execute following query of firebase.
here yourref is ref to your Childs where all entry is placed.

```
yourref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  let useremail = value?["Sender"] as? String ?? ""
  if useremail == "aa@bb.com"{
      //your local variable num
      num = num + value?["Number"] as? Int ?? 0
  }
  // ...
  }) { (error) in
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly.